# How can I make grails accept a belongsTo relation that can be null?

Tags: grails

What I am trying to do is have two domains that reference each other. However one does not necessarily have the other or belongs to the other. Each object from both domains can reference 0 or 1 object from the other domain.

I have this code, but it doesnt work:

```
class Domain1{

    //declare some vars
          ...

    static belongsTo = [domain2Object:Domain2]

    static constraints = {
    domain2Object(nullable:true)
    }
}
```

Using hasOne with the nullable:true constrain works, but it doesnt work if the other side has the same thing. The point is that I want to be able to delete any object from any of the domains that is referring an object from the another domain without causing the referred object to be deleted as well. So like I said, no object belongs to the other, they just reference each other.

=========================================================================================
Response:

using this in both domain classes:

```
class ClassB {
   static hasOne = [classA:ClassA]

   def beforeDelete = {
      classA?.delete()
   }
}

static constraints = {
    classA(nullable:true)
}
```

I get this error when i try to add an object of any of the two classes leaving the other class blank:

"Integrity constraint violation - no parent FK24742AC1AA048190 table: PENDINGORDER"

Answer (score 1):

You can use "hasOne" onDelete event.

```
class ClassB {
   static hasOne = [classA:ClassA]

   def beforeDelete = {
      classA?.delete()
   }
}
```

[Events and Auto Timestamping](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20%28GORM%29.html#5.5.1%20Events%20and%20Auto%20Timestamping)

I guess the exception happens because you are trying to delete an object by it's relation in the beforeDelete event. Remove your relation before deleting it like this  :

```
class ClassA {
  ClassB classB

  static constraints = {
      classB nullable: true
  }
}

class ClassB {
    ClassA classA

    static constraints = {
      classA nullable: true
    }

    def beforeDelete = {
      classA?.classB? = null
      classA?.delete(flush:true)
    }
}
```

Comment: I have added a response as an edit to my question since I cant figure out how to format properly on a stackOverflow comment box.

Comment: so i guess the question is how can i have a classA that belongs to another classB, but yet have a null value for that parent classB and be able to instantiate an object from classA without specifying the classB that the classA belongs to?

Comment: ...or even better, how can i have a hasOne relation that doesnt require a corresponding belongsTo relation on the other side.

Comment: There is smth wrong with this: 

 def beforeDelete = {
      classA?.classB? = null
      classA?.delete(flush:true)
    }

I keep getting red Xes whatever i do with it.